# How to create a custom display with datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am new to VB.net, I am working on a project for deliver service. I am currently using a standard Data grid view connected to a dataset, datasource, table adapter to display the pending items received. However, I was wondering if someone could help me to have the same pending items display like the second image below:

[image]

Comment: You have multiple data items in one 'thing': a date or two, a name, an issue/problem, a status and an address and more.  Thats not really something the DGV is meant for.  A user control on a scrolling panel might work

Comment: Hi Putonix, thank you for your quick response. What method is called to perform this action?

Comment: You might look at using the `DataRepeater` control from the VB PowerPacks library.  It basically is what Plutonix describes but does much of the heavy lifting for you.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/windows-forms/power-packs-controls

Comment: Thanks jmcilhinney, I have tried your suggestion and it works. Thanks everyone for your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `VirtualMode` and a `DataGridViewImageColumn`. Draw the image you want in `CellValueNeeded`:

```
Public Class Form1
  'Add a DataGridView called DataGridView1 to the form
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim dtb As New DataTable()
    dtb.Columns.Add("Col1", GetType(String))
    dtb.Columns.Add("Col2", GetType(Integer))
    dtb.Rows.Add("AA", 123)
    dtb.Rows.Add("CC", 234)
    DataGridView1.VirtualMode = True
    DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells
    DataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewImageColumn() With {.Name = "img"})
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dtb
  End Sub

  Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueNeeded(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueNeeded
    If DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "img" AndAlso e.ColumnIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex < DataGridView1.ColumnCount Then
      Select Case e.RowIndex
        Case 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 2
          Dim drw As DataRow = DirectCast(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, DataRowView).Row
          Dim strCol1Value As String = CStr(drw("Col1"))
          Dim intCol2Value As Integer = CInt(drw("Col2"))
          Dim bmp As New Bitmap(100, 50)
          Using gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
            Dim brs As Brush = New System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(New Point(0, 0), New Point(100, 50), Color.Black, Color.LightGray)
            gfx.FillRectangle(brs, New RectangleF(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height))
            gfx.DrawString(strCol1Value, New Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.Red, New PointF(0, 0))
            gfx.DrawString(intCol2Value.ToString, New Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.Yellow, New PointF(0, 25))
          End Using
          e.Value = bmp
        Case DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
          Dim bmp As New Bitmap(100, 50)
          Using gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
            gfx.DrawString("NEW", New Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.Red, New PointF(0, 0))
          End Using
          e.Value = bmp
        Case Else
      End Select
    End If
  End Sub       
End Class
```